5 deep Apex soql: System.QueryException: SOQL statements cannot query aggregate relationships more than 1 level away from the root entity object
Given V61 (Summer 24), we get Apex support for 5 deep parent->child relationships. This was previously available only for REST API calls.
So, I gave it a try:
for (Account account:  [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id , (SELECT Id
                          FROM OpportunityLineItems)
                          FROM Opportunities)
                        FROM Account LIMIT 1] ) {}

This generates exception: System.QueryException: SOQL statements cannot query aggregate relationships more than 1 level away from the root entity object.
I'm definitely running at V61
61.0 APEX_CODE,INFO;APEX_PROFILING,ERROR;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;NBA,INFO;SYSTEM,ERROR;VALIDATION,ERROR;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WAVE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO

What am I doing wrong?

Turns out, the feature doesn't work if used as SOQL within a for loop as shown in the OP.
This works fine (no SOQL in for loop):
Account[] accounts = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id , (SELECT Id 
                        FROM OpportunityLineItems)
                        FROM Opportunities)
                        FROM Account LIMIT 1
                     ];

I would expect this to be documented in SOQL for loops but it is not (Summer 24)
